# Set dropdown menu list items to same width

Tags: html, css

In order for you to understand what I mean I've created a JSfiddle [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/Relborg/mZhqp/3/). Basically if you look at the dropdown menus on 'Products' and 'Contact us' each list item is wide enough to fit the content. This gives the dropdown menu a 'broken' look. I'd like all the list items to be as wide as the widest list item in the list. (To see what I mean please have a look at the attached mockup).

Also because the 'primay links' e.g. 'Home' and 'About us' have a bottom border when you hover over them it also creates a little irritation when you go on and hover on the dropdown items, i.e the dropdown menu moves up 5px. And I have no idea how to fix this.

Very important: **I do not want to set static widths for the list items!**

Mockup of what it should look like:

[image]

```
//Ignore this comment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting

```
li a {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0);
}
.secondary-list li {
    float: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZhqp/5/)

By setting an invisible border on the anchors the hover will just change the color instead of adding the border and moving the following elements down by 5px.

Removing the float of the second level `li` elements makes them use the full width of the list (= width of the widest `li`).

Comment: Thank you very much, I like the solution by just changing the color of the border. Works well. Although the jsfiddle you link to seems to be broken a bit? Also I DO have 'display: block' on the a tags inside the dropdown list, doesn't seem to work

Comment: There was no `display: block` on the `a` tags in the fiddle in your question. And what is broken in this fiddle? It looks to me exactly the same (apart from the changes mentioned in my answer) as your link?

Comment: That's really strange. Just follow my link again. the a tags have display: block through the .primary-link and .secondary-link CSS classes. Also if I could send you a screenshot of your js fiddle I would. Maybe jsfiddle is being weird today.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your old fiddle hat `.primary-links` in the CSS which of course didn't apply to anything. See my last edit to the answer.